# How to Import bookmarks programmatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to import a lot of bookmarks programmatically. Looking at the docs (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#property-MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE) there is a rate limit on inserts set to 2 per minute.

A couple of questions...

1. Have I understood the docs correctly. I can really only add bookmarks at a rate of 2 per minute?
2. Empirically, it appears that the "import bookmarks from html" option doesn't have this rate limit. How come? and is there a way to programmatically trigger an import?

Comment: could you add a link to the docs you are mention

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#property-MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it does seem like it.
2. It seems that the default bookmark manager uses an undocumented function `chrome.bookmarks.import`, cf the [chromium source code](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=blob;f=chrome/browser/resources/enhanced_bookmark_manager/js/main.js;hb=e84b17696d1f40b7bc59699567cb30c98e4c2acc#l1088). It's mapped to the C++ class [`BookmarksImportFunction`](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=blob;f=chrome/browser/extensions/api/bookmarks/bookmarks_api.h;h=4e7c978333386083a1487a8ed7b6579ee04b02b2;hb=e84b17696d1f40b7bc59699567cb30c98e4c2acc#l300), which in turn calls [`BookmarksImportFunction::RunImpl`](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=blob;f=chrome/browser/extensions/api/bookmarks/bookmarks_api.cc;hb=e84b17696d1f40b7bc59699567cb30c98e4c2acc#l979). That function opens a dialog box to select the file to import, and then calls the C++ bookmark importer on it.

My guess is that this importer is not subject to this limit.

I tried to use this undocumented function, but it doesn't open a dialog box.

Comment: Many thanks for the digging and the terrifying, albeit correct, answer. It's hard to believe that in 2013, Google could invent something an order of magnitude slower than paper tape.